# Is $\mathbb Z$ a submanifold of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Is $\mathbb Z$ a sub-manifold of $\mathbb R$? If yes, what kind of sub-manifold it is?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's a $0$-dimensional manifold but is not compact or even bounded. We retain Hausdorffness and second countability for obvious reasons. (Note every $0$-dimensional manifold is a disjoint union of points - that is they are discrete spaces classified topologically by their cardinality.)